# How to Enable Verbose in Maven Ant Run Plugin. (Maven)

Tags: maven, ant, maven-plugin, maven-antrun-plugin

How do I enable verbose in maven-ant-run plugin. Currently I have my execution as this. But do not know, where to set the verbose flag.

```
<executions>
    <execution>
        <id>create-properties-file</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
        <inherited>false</inherited>
        <configuration>
            <exportAntProperties>true</exportAntProperties>
            <failOnError>true</failOnError>
            <target>
                <ant antfile="./src/main/resources/APPInstallation/properties-build.xml">
                    <target name="get-properties" />
                </ant>
                <property name="compile_classpath" refid="maven.compile.classpath"/>
                <echo message="compile classpath: ${compile_classpath}"/>
            </target>
        </configuration>
    </execution>
</executions>
```

Any pointers would be helpful. Thanks!

Comment: You can run the entire Maven build with `-X` flag